# Wordpress when I have set static front page then home page not working

Tags: wordpress

I have created a page in admin panel. When I have set it to static front page from settings > reading the home page is totally blank. But when I removed this page as a home page and run the url like demosite.com/pageslug then it is working fine.

Can any one please tell me why it is happening. Is this a htaccess issue?

Comment: Change your permalinks settings from the current option, to another. Save, and then change it again... If problem still persists, check if there's an actual code in your current theme's homepage template.

Comment: I have changed the permalink settings but issue not fixed. Home page template is working fine if i not set as a static front page.

Comment: check theme folder front-page.php file ?? yes and remove php file

Comment: I am using front-page.php template for home page.

Comment: front-page.php file and template name change

Comment: Okay so i need to change the template name, now it was "Front Page Template" and i need to change it like "new home template". Is it right?